# Passing a value to a hidden input with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

I have a bunch of links with ID's 1 - n, and I want to pass that ID to a hidden input in my form (I have numerous links but want to only have one form rather than generating thousands of extra lines of HTML making a form for each ID).

The link looks like this:

```
<a href='javascript:$("#removeSave").submit()' id="n">Remove</a>
```

The form with hidden input looks like this:

```
<form action="/php/removeSave.php" method="POST" id="removeSave">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value=""/>
</form>
```

Any help?

Comment: The link given doesn't appear to have an id. Furthermore, just for clarity's sake, ids cannot start with a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sets the value of the hidden `input` with the id `ID` to the `id` of the `a` element before it submits the `form`.

```
<a href='#' id='n' onclick='$("#ID").val(this.id);$("#removeSave").submit();'>Remove</a>


<form action="/php/removeSave.php" method="POST" id="removeSave">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID" value=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: According to ISO8879 (Referred to here http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2), an ID attribute must start with a letter (and so `... id="123" ...` would not be valid. You could, of course, prefix it with "id" or something and then use something like `this.id.replace(/\D/g,"")` to strip non-numeric characters out.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the full context of the "Remove" link, wherein the ID would be noted, so I will presume a format, and you can adapt from there.

```
<!-- HTML //-->

<!-- Format for Each Element. "123" is the ID here //-->
<div id="element123">
  This is Element 123 (ID#123)
  <a href="/php/removeSave.php?ID=123">Remove</a>
</div>

<!-- The Form at the Bottom of the Page //-->
<form id="removeSave" method="POST" action="/php/removeSave.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="" />
</form>
```

The jQuery Segment

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 // Clicks of Links starting with "/php/removeSave.php?ID="
  $('a[href^="/php/removeSave.php?ID="]').click(function(e){
   // Don't let the Link act as a basic link
    e.preventDefault();
   // Get the Link HREF attribute
    href = $(this).attr('href');
   // Derive the Form ID and ID Value
    bits = href.match(/^\/php\/([^\.]+)\.php\?ID=(\d+)/);
    formID = bits[1];
    elementID = bits[2];
   // Set the Field Values and Submit the Form
    $form = $('#'+formID);
    $form.find('input[name="ID"]').val(elementID);
    $form.submit();
  });

});
</script>
```

Benefits of this method?

Graceful Degradation - so long as your PHP scripts can also handle GET variables, if this page is loaded from a browser which does not have Javascruipt enabled, or is unable to load jQuery, clicking on the "Remove" links will still perform the expected action.

Opportunity for AJAX-ification - instead of all those other actions inside the `.click(function(e){` section, you could use jQuery's `$.post()` function and the query string segment of the link's HREF to pass this request straight to the handler and manipulate the page without having to do a full-page reload.